# Copyright symbol for a Pyramid app

Tags: python, character-encoding, pyramid

I am trying to include a copyright symbol in the output of a view method in a Pyramid application. This is literally the method:

```
def get_cpyright(self):
    cpyright = ["My Super App &copy; 2012"]
    if (datetime.datetime.now().year > 2012):
        cpyright.append(" - %d " % datetime.datetime.now().year)
    return " ".join(cpyright)
```

However, when it renders out to the application, the web-page reads:

> My Super App &copy; 2012

In straight web-dev, I could use `&copy;`or `&#169;` I would get the the © character. This is not the case when rendering the string in the tuple.

How can I get the copyright symbol to show up? I see it on Pyramid's own docs, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you think to mess up your encoding in source code files. Try opening it in a bunch of different editors over time and you'll probably end up breaking the encoding sooner or later.

I would simply do this:

```
print unichr(169)
```

Editing your function I would replace your first line with this:

```
cpyright = ''.join(["My Super App ", unichr(169), " 2012"])
```

Comment: I disagree; the `join` and extra syntax is worse.  You can even keep the numeric value separated from the rest if that's your concern, as Python concatenates adjacent string literals in its lexer.  `'My Super App ' u'\u00a9' ' 2012' == u'My Super App \u00a9 2012'`

Comment: The only thing about that particular solution I'm really against is the hexadecimal representation. But that might boil down to a matter of personal taste. The adjacent string literal concatenation is nice, though :)

Comment: Nobody looks up Unicode characters by _decimal_ value ;-)  (I do agree that it is a matter of taste.)

Comment: I did this without the ''.join() and it works like a charm. Here's thew new format: 
`cpyright = ["My Super App " + unichr(169) +" 2012"]`

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that your template variable is being escaped for an HTML context and &copy; is escaped into &amp;copy;.

If you're using chameleon templating you can use ${structure:variable} to avoid it being escaped when displaying (as you've already escaped it in your method). You can also wrap it in an object that has a __html__ method which returns the content. See [In Pyramid, how do I return raw HTML from a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931492/in-pyramid-how-do-i-return-raw-html-from-a-view) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Why not [just make the Python file unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code), make sure the output html is an appropriate encoding and write the copyright symbol like this?

```
def get_cpyright(self):
    cpyright = [u"My Super App © 2012"]
    if (datetime.datetime.now().year > 2012):
        cpyright.append(" - %d " % datetime.datetime.now().year)
    return " ".join(cpyright)
```

Comment: @JonMitten If the python source file is not yours to change, doesn't that make it impossible to implement the fix in the answer you accepted?

Comment: I should say, changing the encoding would require my whole team to consider the change. I applied the fix in-line, and it worked. We're on Python 2.7, so I assume ASCII, but for all I know, the encode type could already be UTF-8.