# HTMLParser unescape does not pass < or > unescaped in Pyramid app

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, pyramid, html-parser

The title says most of it.  Python3.3 using a Pyramid app framework (-s starter) 
Adding this code to the views.py controller:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser()

string = '<p>Hi there!</p>';
return dict( string=h.unescape(string) )
```

where return dict(..) is handed off to a template with a simple ${string}  marker in it, the result in the web browser is always to show the angle brackets instead of rendering them as tags.  I.e, the web page shows:  <p>Hi there!</p>

I need to be able to pass user content (html with markup) through to the template for it to render inline.  What more do I need to do?

Comment: What `HTMLParser` is it? In Python 3.3 there's `HTMLParser` class which is placed in module `html.parser` not `HTMLParser` and it does [not](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/html.parser.html#htmlparser-methods) have any `unescape` method...

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: This is Python 2 more likely. The `.unescape()` method is notoriously undocumented; it is still present in Python 3.3.

Comment: The `.unescape()` method is to turn HTML entities back into regular characters, and is entirely orthogonal to what you want; mark strings safe for inclusion in your template.

Comment: What template language are you using to render these strings?

Comment: Yes, I am running 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templating engine is escaping the variable, because just about every templating engine does that.

You need to structure your templates to not escape variables.  This differs in mako , chameleon, etc.

IIRC, the `starter` scaffold uses Chameleon's `.pt` templates.

If that's what your'e using, this other StackOverflow question answers your question fully: [Python Pyramid & Chameleon templating language escapes html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346295/python-pyramid-chameleon-templating-language-escapes-html)